# Get last changes on site

Tags: python, algorithm, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to create software in Python which monitoring sites when changes have happened. At the moment I have periodic task and check content of site with previous version. Is there any easier way to check if content of site has been changed, maybe time of last changes, so to avoid downloading content everu time ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `HEAD` HTTP method and look at the `Date-Modified` and `ETag` headers, etc. before actually downloading the full content again.

However nothing guarantees that the server will actually update these headers when the entity's (URL's) content changes, or indeed even respond properly to the `HEAD` method.

Answer (score 1):

Altough it doesn't answer your question I think its worth to mention that you don't have to store the previous version of website to look for changes. You can just count `md5` sum of it and store this sum, then count it for the new version and check if they are equal.

And about the question itself, AKX gave a great answer - just look for `Date-Modified` header, but remember it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks, I am using hash at the moment but I need to download content to provide new hash to compare with old, but problem is when content is to long and I monitor lot off sites.